# Grunt serve command keeps waiting forever

Tags: gruntjs

I am using 'grunt serve' command for serving my application, but it shows waiting... Can someone please guide me what could be the possible reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Serve usually starts a server and then waits forever for requests.

Comment: Yes, so that's  my problem